# creating table like structure with retrievable value in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dropdown

I am creating an app that contains a table structured view, in this view the user select a value from a drop down corresponds with the row content

I am using a map to manipulate the row content,

```
var data = {
  'CT': {
    's1': {
      1001: 3,
      1002: 6,
      1003: 3,
      1004: 3,
      1008: 4,
      1009: 2,
    },
  }
};
```

The table format should be like this
(It is Hard coded for demo)

[image]

and also when a button pressed i need all data in the table. code, credit and also the the selected dropDownItem(String) for a calculation.
The DropDown is same for all rows but i want to know the selecteditem for which code and credit

**I tried with DataTable**

but don't know how to manipulate the Row with map
also don't know how to retrieve(get) the data in the table for calculation

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739638/13997210) for dropdown only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create some lists to store the needed data(**code, gradepoints, and the default values of dropdown**)

so:

```
class _ViewScreenState extends State<ViewScreen> {
  List? selectedValues = []; // for storing the dropdown data
  List? creditsDetails = []; // for gradePoint
  List? codeDetais = []; // for code 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    creditsDetails = getPtsCodeDetails('CT', 's1')[0];
    codeDetais = getPtsCodeDetails('CT', 's1')[1];
    selectedValues = setSelectedValues(creditsDetails!.length); // creditDetails's  number of default value in a list
  }
```

the `getPtsCodeDetails` would be like this for changing the data from map to list

```
List getPtsCodeDetails(String? dp, String? sem) {
  var ptscode = [];
  ptscode.add(data[dp]![sem]!.values.toList());
  ptscode.add(data[dp]![sem]!.keys.toList());
  return ptscode;
}
```

and We are using the ListView.builder for the table(Didn't check with DataTable yet)
We are basically using the `selectedValues` for DropDowns items and changing the value of the selected Dropdown's index's value in `setState((){};)` so the change will reflect on ui also

```
child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: creditsDetails!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        codeDetais![index].toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                      Text(creditsDetails![index].toString()),
                      DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: selectedValues![index],
                        onChanged: (String? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedValues![index] = value;
                          });
                        },
                        items: grades.map((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(
                              value,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

If you have any better solution let me know

Thanks